Tkinter Designer Invalid prompt path
Tkinter Designer is a tool that easily builds the interface diagram of figma online design into the interface of Python's Tkinter library。Tkinter Designer is a tool that easily builds the interface diagram of figma online design into the interface of Python's Tkinter library. His Github URL is: https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer。
When using the Tkinter Designer tool, prompted to enter a valid Figma address, the prompt message is as follows:
Invalid URL!
Please enter a valid file URL.

问题如下图所示：
enter image description here
But I repeatedly watched the instructional video in the README file of Tkinter Designer tool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd -JJjduWeQ did not notice any issues with copying Figma file links. If possible, could you help me identify the problem and reply to me? thank you very much.
This is the link to my Figma file: https://www.Figma.com/proto/ShOcdst9h63Zw461pJfcft/TkTools ？ Node ID=1-2&Node Type=canvas&t=sHkyeDhgp6XskhMx-1&Scale=Minimum Scale&Content Scale=Fixed&Page ID=0% 3A1&Starting Node ID=1% 3A2&Share=1
This is my first time asking a question, and I have described my problem as much as possible. If there is any problem, please point it out. thank you.
.....................

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looking into the source code file gui.py of tkinter designer, the valid URL should start with https://www.figma.com/file/... or https://www.figma.com/design/....
